# Update selected rows with selected results from another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named "example" and in one column "colname2" I have string data like below.

```
colname1   colname2          colname3
 101     this is - test
 50      this is - test2
 105     this is - test31ws
```

I need to do following things

1. select where colname1 > 100 and
2. split the string of colname2 with "-" and take the last part of the "-" and
3. add the last part to the colname3

So the output should look like this

```
colname1   colname2          colname3
 101     this is - test        test
 50      this is - test2
 105     this is - test31ws    test31ws
```

I am using oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` and `regexp_substr()`;

```
select t.*,
       (case when colname1 > 100 then trim(regexp_substr(colname2, '[^-]+', 1, 2))
        end) as colname3
from t;
```

This will return `NULL` if there is no hyphen.

Comment: It appears that you should trim a space.

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . In the end, I agree with you.  This is not what the OP specifically asks for, but it is what the data looks like and what reason suggests.

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTR` is the simplest and, probably, most effective. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table example
  2    (colname1 number,
  3     colname2 varchar2(20),
  4     colname3 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into example
  2    (select 101, 'this is - test'    , null from dual union
  3     select 50 , 'this is - test2'   , null from dual union
  4     select 105, 'this is - test31ws', null from dual
  5    );

3 rows created.

SQL> update example set
  2    colname3 = trim(substr(colname2, instr(colname2, '-') + 1))
  3  where colname1 > 100;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from example;

  COLNAME1 COLNAME2             COLNAME3
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        50 this is - test2
       101 this is - test       test
       105 this is - test31ws   test31ws

SQL>
```